# in iPad tableview shows more records when navgigate back from another view inside a popover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a popover view which displays a table with two rows and the size of the popover is adjusted to show only those two rows. After i click any one of the rows i navigate forward to a new table view and the popover size increases accordingly. when i navigate back to the original table view having two rows the popover size increases by one row. It shows a three rows with a empty third row.

Please find my code below.

in initWithFrame for the table view i set the value for popover using contentsizeforviewinPopover. works fine when the view loads

After navigating back i am setting the same value(contentsizeforviewinPopover) inside viewwillAppear. But now the view has three rows.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: How do you calculate the size for the popOver? Have you tried changing the call to setContentsizeforviewinPopover in viewDidAppear?

Comment: I calculate the size of the popover using height of row obtained from heightforrowatindexpath. If there are tiw rows i multplyit by 2.

Comment: And what's the number of rows in the moment you calculate it? Can you post some code?

Comment: [ender]I have fixed it and Thanks for you support. Please find my answer below.Also embedded the link from stackoverflow where i got the answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it rectified. When the initial table view navigatesforward to the next table view i will set the value for contentsizeforviewinPopover to zero in viewdiddisappear. Again when in navigate back, the popover displays with proper size with the proper values present in viewwillappear.

Comment: answer courtesy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with you table datasource. As you said that popover size get changed and also there is an empty row in the table. I think your datasource get updated with blank data.

Please check your datasource in between your navigation.

Thanks