# Change contentSizeForViewInPopover on navigationController push on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, navigationcontroller, uipopover, contentsize

I have a UIPopoverController with navigationController and bunch of subviews. The size of the popover is set just before it's shown like this:

```
[self.myPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
```

That works fine. The popover is shown with adjusted size. When another view is pushed on navigation stack the size of a popover is set again - need different height - in viewWillAppear method:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 700);
```

This also works fine. When I go back to a previous view the size does not change.

I added the same call in viewWillAppear in first view but the view does not resize.

How can I manage resizing of popover when navigating between views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this hack:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    return CGSizeMake(320, 200);
}

- (void) forcePopoverSize 
{
    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
    CGSize fakeMomentarySize = CGSizeMake(currentSetSizeForPopover.width - 1.0f, 
                                          currentSetSizeForPopover.height - 1.0f);
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = fakeMomentarySize;
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self forcePopoverSize];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = currentSetSizeForPopover;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky one. I tried many things and finally got this one working. It just might work for you, too.

In my `contentViewController` i keep a reference to `UIPopoverController` *parent;

This reference is set during initialization of `UIPopoverController` and it's content.
This of course might not fit directly into your view hierarchy. Code in `UIViewController`
that shows `UIPopowerController` is something like:

```
if (self.popoverController == nil) {
    _contentController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController"
                                                                 bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_contentController]; 
    _contentController.parent = popover;
    [popover setPopoverContentSize: CGSizeMake(520.0,580.0)];

    popover.delegate = self;

    self.popoverController = popover;
}
```

And when i want to dynamically change content size from within `contentViewController` i use:

```
-(void)setNewSize:(CGSize) newSize {

    [_parent setPopoverContentSize:newSize animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @BorutTomazin: i know - it's actually ugly :) but after 8 hours of work i finally found one thing that worked. I'll probably try to find more elegant solution for this once... probably. I'll try the link you posted above.

Comment: Yeah I know. Sometimes is ugly and working better than nice and not working. :) Let me know if you find better solution. Thanks!