# Popover resizing broken in iOS 5.1

Tags: ios5, uipopovercontroller

I have a popover in an app and it doesn't resize to what I set. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav) but it still doesn't work in iOS 5.1. I switched to the ios 5.0 simulator and it worked again. Am I missing something?

*EDIT*

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 137.0);
```

In viewDidAppear:

```
self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 137.0);
```

Comment: Can you post how you are re-sizing your popover?

Comment: Is this popover the master in a UISplitViewController?

Comment: Yes it is the master in a UISplitViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it has to be a "bug" or a change in iOS 5.1. Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010436-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) does not do a popover in a splitview. I have disabled the swipe gesture though by calling setPresentsWithGesture on the splitViewController. It is annoying swiping and having the master view come up.