# Resize popover controller in storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipopovercontroller

I have 2 view controllers and the 2nd view controller has a table view in it
I have used storyboard for this purpose and for transition from 1st to 2nd view controller i'm using a popover controller. The problem is since i'm using a table view controller in 2nd view controller, when i click on did select row at index path , a view comes but along with the previous popover size. I'm stuck at this as how to dynamically resize when i click on cell
,Any possible help will be appreciated?

p.s- Please note i'm not using any IBOulet to popover controller and not creating it by code also.Earloer i have used setcontentsize for resizing popovers but with story board i'm stuck.

Comment: Hello ma'm I'm not using any of the code to create a popover when i click on the cell , i have a popover which i made from the storyboard. My question was to resize the popover in the storyboard

Comment: Have you tried this setContentSizeForViewInPopover?

Comment: I have set contentsize when im using the popover by code but dunno what to do here

Comment: Please post some of your code

Comment: Either the popover should have a IBOutlet so that we can handle it by code or the popover should be produced by code . Here the popover is just a transition seque between 2 view controllers, is there any way to handle transition seque's

Comment: have set Identifier to your popover segue?

Answer (score 1):

Here are ways you can try

1. Create ViewController which will be placed in popover, select it and navigate to Utilities pane > Attributes Inspector > Set Size to Freeform
2. Select popover segue and navigate to Utilities pane > Attributes Inspector > Set Identifier to "yourIdentifier"
3. 

**FIRST TRY**

Change the size of ViewController by selecting its View and navigating to Utilities pane->Size Inspector [**see if you can get expected size**]

**SECOND TRY** - Try this inside the view from which you are calling popOverViewController

```
    UIPopoverController *popover; // define this in .h as ivar

    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
    {
         UIButton *anchor = (UIButton*)sender;
         UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];    
         popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
               initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
         [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)]; // here see if you can get expected size
         [popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame 
                                  inView:anchor.superview 
                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

**THIRD TRY**

Please look at Trick by krasnyk (accepted answer) for [Forcing Popover Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav)

Comment: Hello i have lost hope on connecting by seque so i used a popover made through code and set its size on a button click.Thanks for the sincere help bhargavi.