# UIPopoverViewController does not resize properly on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have `UIPopoverController` in my application. It contains `UINavigationController`. When I show `UIPopoverController` it uses correct content size of top view controller. When I push view controller `UIPopoverController` is getting resized (that is what I expect). But when I pop back to previous view controller, it does not getting resized.
I used code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav). But it does not help.
Everything works fine for iOS 7.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution, but still looking for more elegant one.

Add `@property (nonatomic, weak) UIPopoverController *popover;` to first controller in navigation stack and call `[self.popover setPopoverContentSize:self.preferredContentSize animated:YES];` in place where popover should be resized.

Comment: but popover property should be assigned with something?(e.g. self.popovercontroller just for ex.)

Comment: yes. you'r right. that's why i was looking for more elegant solution