# UIPopOverController shrinking when presenting alert controller

Tags: storyboard, ios8, uipopovercontroller, uialertcontroller, universal-storyboard

I have the following UIPopOverController on iPad. This is an iOS 8 app with universal storyboards. In XCode, I have selected the segue of this as "Present as Popover".

[image]

Whenever this view controller presents a UIAlertController, this happens:

[image]

The popover shrinks to a weird size. The UIAlertController is presented from the pop over as:

```
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Error", comment: "A simple error label"), message: NSLocalizedString("This account is already linked to the app.", comment: "A string describing the problem"), preferredStyle: .Alert)
        var action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Simple string"), style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            self.usernameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            self.passwordTextField.text = ""
            return
        })
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have not played with the constraints of the view controllers at all, so I Have no idea why this is happening. What's the correct way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Do you got any solution for your issue? because i have same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still looking for one.

Comment: Apparently this bug makes a return in iOS 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug with iOS 8.0.2 and below. All my devices are updated to iOS 8.1 now. I haven't changed my code and all my popovers don't shrink when they present anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me. `nav.preferredContentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 480);`
My code is below, may be help you.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];
nav.preferredContentSize =CGSizeMake(320, 480);
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late now, but I've occurred same issue on iOS9.0. 
I have a `UINavigationController` controller with root `UIViewController` placed inside `UIPopoverController`. After presenting `UIAlertController` from `UIViewController` the popover shrinks to alert view size.
After some researching I came with this solution:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    CGSize preferredContentSize = self.preferredContentSize;
    CGSize fakeMomentarySize    = CGSizeMake(preferredContentSize.width + 1.0f, preferredContentSize.height + 1.0f);
    self.preferredContentSize   = fakeMomentarySize;
    self.preferredContentSize   = preferredContentSize;

    CGRect frame    = self.view.frame;
    frame.size      = [self preferredContentSize];
    self.view.frame = frame;

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
}
```

I've put this code in my UIViewController. For some reason after dismissing alert view no `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods are called and navigation controller delegate also doesn't reply to this move so view controller doesn't take part in calculating it's size. So I've put it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. The magic with setting `preferredContentSize` is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752394/popover-with-embedded-navigation-controller-doesnt-respect-size-on-back-nav). Also I needed to restore view frame because it still got shrunk. `UIViewController` `preferredContentSize` should be set elsewhere earlier.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you present the `UIViewController` with `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext` and show an alert with `UIAlertController`. Use `UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext` instead.