# Setting preferredContentSize dynamically doesn't change the size of the popover on iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I want to change the `preferredContentSize` if the content of the table view in my popover changes. Imho this worked so far by using

```
self.preferredContentSize = myTableView.contentSize;
```

but now it doesn't work anymore for iOS 8. The popover doesn't resize despite the sizes are correct.

Yesterday auto update did it's work and now I'm using Xcode 6.1.1. Don't know if that's the reason.

Are you experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: Use can force the table view layout using [tableView layoutIfNeeded]. You can do this in your own implementation of preferredContentSize method in your view controller. Also you may need to set the estimated row height (tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0) and set automatic row height mode for the table (table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension).

Comment: Thank you for your tips. Currently I'm using a similar approach ([see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26964838/426227)) and it does currently the job for me on iOS 8.