# Dynamic cell height and preferredContentSize

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/426227) algorithm to have a multiline label in a cell. I want to present the table view in a popover. Therefore I set the `preferredContentSize` similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964838/426227) in `viewDidAppear`.

But if I query the `contentSize` of the tableview I get the wrong height. It seems that it always takes the default height of the row (44f) despite my last cell has a dynamic height (depending on the text in the multiline label).

What I've noted is that `viewDidAppear` is called before the calculation of the height of all cells has been finished. What does that mean? Here is the excerpt of the index paths which are queried in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
2015-11-13 14:49:20.592 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7eb27130> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.594 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e904750> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.595 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e9f7730> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.596 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e9fbd60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.596 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e91bee0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.597 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e90bde0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 1}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.598 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e9081e0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 2}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.599 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e902d30> {length = 2, path = 1 - 3}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.599 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e900b10> {length = 2, path = 1 - 4}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.600 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24470> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.601 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24590> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.601 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24570> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.601 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24580> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.601 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24a60> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.601 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24bf0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 1}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.602 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24d80> {length = 2, path = 1 - 2}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.602 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec24f10> {length = 2, path = 1 - 3}
2015-11-13 14:49:20.602 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec250a0> {length = 2, path = 1 - 4}
// viewDidAppear is called setting the preferredContentSize
2015-11-13 14:49:31.374 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e80fb20> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:31.378 [53865:2230330] Adaptive: <NSIndexPath: 0x7e9088b0> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}
2015-11-13 14:49:31.379 [53865:2230330] Default: <NSIndexPath: 0x7ec231c0> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}
```

How can I set the correct `preferredContentSize`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why, but it seems that `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` has an influence on this.

If I get the index path for my dynamic cell I calculate the cell height and use that for the estimation. My code in C# looks like this:

```
public override nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    if (indexPath.Section == 3)
    {
        return this.GetHeightForRow(tableView, indexPath);
    }

    return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
}
```

This seems to work, but I still think this is kind of a hack ...